# Graph API cannot get data from facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I add all 52 permission in Graph API Explorer like this image and click Generate Access Token.

[image]

Then, I search Facebook ID with [this page](https://lookup-id.com/).

After that, I use Facebook ID in graph API to show feed but it not show anything like this image. how to fix it?

[image]

I change many facebook page but same it's not show any data